# Multi-level Cascading List View in a HTML Page

Tags: html, css, listview

How can we easily implement something like this? Preferably within .Net framework, or just standard html, css ...

The first column has a vertical list; If you click on one item, the second column is shown with the sublist; so on.

This is something like the file system navigation in MAC OS.

Answer (score 1):

While I suppose a tree could be achievable with CSS, I think the resulting code would be rather daunting and not very flexible or reliable.

You did not mention JavaScript, but have you seen **[jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/)**?

Alternatively, you could develop the entire hierarchy of lists within .NET, and give a path argument to the .NET app that tells it how much of the hierarchy to render. (I'm not a .NET developer though, so can't help with this.) The major drawback to this is that it would require a page refresh for a user to navigate the tree.

Comment: I don't really want a tree view, actually, although logically it is a tree structure. Rendering a tree is a waste of space in my case. In other words, when clicking on an item on the first level, I want the sub list to span over the entire second column...

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. Check out http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#sample3. You could probably modify the script so that it works upon click instead of hover.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, It sounds like jsTree would be your best bet, but you can do horizontal nested list's as well in plain html. I use 
http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Your BE developer could then create ItemRepeaters (or a control) in .net for the li's.